# Apache proxy - Dynamic cookies

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to do something I though would be quite simple, but I struggle :)

I have a reverse proxy running on Apache. I'm trying to get urls like /a/b?session=1-2 to be proxied to a diffrent host with url /a/b/.
This bit is done, but I'd like to add a cookie when proxying the request, whose value is the first digit before the "-" in the session parameter (from the original request).

I home someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add to your config:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /localapp1 /app1/
```